# Different count results from django and database directly

Tags: django

Does Django limit the number of records it checks by default? I am getting two different results from Django shell and database directly.

Database

```
SELECT count(*) FROM datapoints WHERE sk='dfVRRZOe2O68dEA';

count
-------
11519
```

Python django shell.

```
>>> key = 'dfVRRZOe2O68dEA'
>>> print datapoints.objects.filter(sk=key).count()
10000
>>>
```

Comment: Uhm... no it shouldn't do that. What's the output of `from django.db import connection; print connection.queries` when `DEBUG` is `True`?

Comment: {u'time': u'0.000', u'sql': u'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM datapoints'}

Comment: I am using a third party database driver (for Cassandra), perhaps there's a bug in that.

Comment: I'd think that's more likely than a bug in Django, `count()` has been working perfectly on a wide variety of systems for a long, long time ;)

Comment: Agreed :) If I run a raw SQL query, it works fine.